# If substring is in a word, get the index value before the word

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-2

Im gone substring a description text after a certain count with `.Substring(0, 100)`. I dont want to break in the middle of a word, if thats the case i would like to get to the first whitespace before the word.

I figure i check if the next character is not a `" "` its in the middle of the word.
My biggest issue is how do step backwards to get the index of the `" "` (whitespace).

this is what i got so far

```
        string description = "a long string";            

        description = Regex.Replace(description, @"(?></?\w+)(?>(?:[^>'""]+|'[^']*'|""[^""]*"")*)>", String.Empty);
        var newString = (description.Count() > 101) ? description.Substring(0, 101) : description;

        //i tried something like this
        var whatIsNext = newString.IndexOf(" ", 100, -20);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for  [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx):

> Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified Unicode character within this instance. The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string.

You want something like this:

```
int index = s.LastIndexOf(' ', 100);
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks Mark. Is there a easy way to check the next character? string i want is 100 but i get 101 just to check if the next is a character.

Answer (score 1):

Use LastIndexOf and apply it to your substring

```
// The string we are searching.
string value = "Dot Net Perls";
//
// Find the last occurrence of ' '.
int index1 = value.LastIndexOf(' ');
```

Link [Info](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lastindexof)

Answer (score 0):

`var whatIsNext = newString.Substring(0, newString.LastIndexOf(' '));`